# Crystal Channelling

Tags: optics, particle-physics, scattering, atoms, crystals

Can someone explain this paragraph especially the bold part in simpler language:

"If it is not in a major crystal direction or plane ("random direction", Fig. 2), it is much more likely to undergo large-angle scattering and hence **its final mean penetration depth is likely to be shorter.**" 
 full article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channelling_(physics)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

let's draw a schematic illustration of ions travelling though a cubic lattice.

[image: Lattice]

Ions travelling in the green direction have a good chance of missing the atoms in the crystal and travelling a long distance. However ions travelling in the red direction will inevitably hit an atom and be scattered.

The difference is simply that the green direction is lined up with the principal axes of the lattice while the red direction is not.